# Why does this div not grow the div container?

Tags: css, positioning, html, 960.gs

The box

```
section.box-products {
```

has all the

```
section.box-products ul li.item {
```

elements in it but even if the `<li>` count increases the box-products div is not increasing in height.

Why?

Code:

```
        <section class="box-products">



            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <h2>
                    Noteworthy
                </h2>
            </div>

            <div class="large-12 columns">

                <ul class="large-block-grid-8">


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/1.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/2.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/3.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/4.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/5.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/6.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/7.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/8.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/9.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/10.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/11.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/12.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/13.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/14.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/15.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/16.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/17.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/18.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/19.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                    <li class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/item/20.jpg">
                        <a href="#" class="name">
                            Sofa Bercelli
                        </a>
                        <p>12.95</p>
                    </li>


                </ul>

            </div>
```

And CSS:

section.box-products {

```
margin-top: 24px;
padding-bottom: 20px;


/*border: 1px solid red;*/

min-height: 220px;

background-color: #fff;

border-bottom: solid 3px #8A8780;
```

}

section.box-products h2 {

```
font-size: 1.3em;
font-weight: 400;
```

}

section.box-products ul li.item {

```
width: 120px;
height: 140px;

margin-top: 12px;
margin-bottom: 12px;

/*border: 1px solid red;*/
```

}

UPDATE:

adding overflow: hidden; fixed the issue!

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question.

Comment: @Musa the code is already there as an URL

Comment: @HerrK Stackoverflow isn't only for answering questions but also for helping people who might come across your question in the future, your link might not be available at that time that's why you should post your code here.

Comment: @HerrK I cannot seem to reproduce your problem, I just added 50 `li` products and the `box-products` seems to grow nicely.

Comment: Ow, I fixed the code already, sorry I forgot to mention that :) I should add the broken code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The children of `<section class="box-products">` are floats and, therefore, ignored (when it comes to height) by the parent. One simple way to get the parent to recognize the floated children is like this:

```
.box-products { overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: What about changing the `li` from floats to `inline-block`?